# Magento2: I want to add layered navigation filter on category page

Tags: magento2, attributes, filter

I have already added a layered navigation filter extension. But I want to add a new attribute filter to my extension.

I have a dimension attribute. I want to filter on dimension attribute like the price attribute

Suppose I have a width 150 inch

I want to search filter like below

```
Under 10
10 - 50
51 - 100
101 - 150
151 - 200
201 - 250
251 - 300
```

Can anyone tell me? How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please let me know which layered navigation filter extension have you added?

Comment: @DharaBhatti I have added Magebees layered navigation filter.

Comment: Have you set "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" option to Price in Admin > Stores > Attributes > Product > Select Dimension attribute to edit?

Comment: Ok, thanks!! I will check and update you.